# Removing White Space each div element

Tags: html, css

Good day guys, [image: the result should be]

As you can see in the image they are stick to each other in desktop view, however on the real code I wasn't been able to do it, I tried to use the overflow but the result is not what I expected. Heres my code https://jsfiddle.net/Jury/0bqpLw1h/1/.. Thank you so much for your help

```
<body>
<div class="body">
    <header>
        <div class="menu-toggle" id="hamburger">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <nav>
            <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="menu">
                <a href="#" class="btn">Contact</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btninfo">Info</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
            <h1 class="possible">Everything is Possible</h1>
            <div class="circle">

            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="about">
        <h1>Helow</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 
                    rgba(0, 31, 63, 0.958), 
                    rgba(0, 31, 63, 0.958) ) 
                    ,url(img/bgmain.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    
}

.overlay{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 transition: opacity 650ms;
 transform: scale(0);
 opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

/* Hamburger Menu */

.menu-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2.5rem;
    right: 2.5rem;
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}

/* End of Hamburger Menu */

/* Navagation Link */
header {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem;
    z-index: 2;
}

nav {
    /* padding-top: 5rem; */
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

nav img {
    height: 7rem;
    margin: 0 0 0 12rem;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    position: relative;
    color: #eee;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0 12rem 0 0;
}

.menu a {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0 .1rem;
    outline: none;
}

.menu a:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}

nav ul li a::before,
nav ul li a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #f4511e;
    left: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
 transition: all .5s;
}

nav ul li a::before{
 top: 0;
 transform-origin: left;
}

nav ul li a::after{
 bottom: 0;
 transform-origin: right;
}

nav ul li a:hover::before,
nav ul li a:hover::after{
 transform: scaleX(1);
}

.btn {
        border: none;
        border-radius: 30px;
        background-color: #f4511e;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 9px;
        width: 70px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btninfo{
    padding: 9px 19px;
}
/* End of Navagation Menu */

/* Content of the Website */

/* .content {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
} */

.possible {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 6rem;
    font-family: "Coiny", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.2rem;
}

.circle { 
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50rem;
    background-color: #6CA9A5;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -75%;
}

.about {
    height: 100vh;
    width:100%;
    background-color: crimson;
    z-index: 3;
    position:absolute;
    /*bottom : 0;*/
}



























/* Media Queries for tablet and mobile */

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    
    .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
    }

    nav {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        text-align: center;
    }

     nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
 
    nav ul li {
        margin-top: 5rem;
    }

     nav ul li a {
        margin 0;
        font-size: 3rem;
    }  

    nav ul li:first-child{
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .overlay.menu-open,
        nav.menu-open{
   display: flex;
   transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1;
    }

  nav img {
      height: 15rem;
      margin: 0;
  }

  .menu {
      margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Coiny|Roboto|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Jury Gregorio - Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <header>
            <div class="menu-toggle" id="hamburger">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <nav>
                <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="menu">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btninfo">Info</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
                <h1 class="possible">Everything is Possible</h1>
                <div class="circle">

                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="about">
            <h1>Helow</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var open = document.getElementById('hamburger');
        var changeIcon = true;

        open.addEventListener("click", function(){

        var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
        var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
        var icon = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle i');

        overlay.classList.toggle("menu-open");
        nav.classList.toggle("menu-open");

        if (changeIcon) {
        icon.classList.remove("fa-bars");
        icon.classList.add("fa-times");

        changeIcon = false;
        }
        else {
        icon.classList.remove("fa-times");
        icon.classList.add("fa-bars");
        changeIcon = true;
        }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Small changes in the css can make the image like look. Just make a small change in .about. and this will work. [output of the below code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oJUd.png)

```
        .about {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: crimson;
            z-index: 3;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: -270px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes along with some brief explanation to the CSS file, in particular, the `.content` and `.circle` selector. Best viewed in desktop environment.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyxh26cp/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Just add this style before your media query also you check it on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v8r463je/

```
 .about {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: crimson;
            z-index: 3;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: -270px;
        }
.content{
    background-color: #0b2947;
}
/* Media Queries for tablet and mobile */
```

Output here

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.body {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient( 
                    rgba(0, 31, 63, 0.958), 
                    rgba(0, 31, 63, 0.958) ) 
                    ,url(img/bgmain.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    
}

.overlay{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.95);
 position: fixed;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 transition: opacity 650ms;
 transform: scale(0);
 opacity: 0;
    display: none;
}

/* Hamburger Menu */

.menu-toggle {
    position: fixed;
    top: 2.5rem;
    right: 2.5rem;
    color: #eeeeee;
    font-size: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
}

/* End of Hamburger Menu */

/* Navagation Link */
header {
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10rem;
    z-index: 2;
}

nav {
    /* padding-top: 5rem; */
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}

nav img {
    height: 7rem;
    margin: 0 0 0 12rem;
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    position: relative;
    color: #eee;
}

.menu {
    margin: 0 12rem 0 0;
}

.menu a {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0 .1rem;
    outline: none;
}

.menu a:last-child{
    margin-right: 0;
}

nav ul li a::before,
nav ul li a::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #f4511e;
    left: 0;
    transform: scaleX(0);
 transition: all .5s;
}

nav ul li a::before{
 top: 0;
 transform-origin: left;
}

nav ul li a::after{
 bottom: 0;
 transform-origin: right;
}

nav ul li a:hover::before,
nav ul li a:hover::after{
 transform: scaleX(1);
}

.btn {
        border: none;
        border-radius: 30px;
        background-color: #f4511e;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 9px;
        width: 70px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btninfo{
    padding: 9px 19px;
}
/* End of Navagation Menu */

/* Content of the Website */

/* .content {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
} */

.possible {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 6rem;
    font-family: "Coiny", sans-serif;
    font-size: 3.2rem;
}

.circle { 
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50rem;
    height: 50rem;
    background-color: #6CA9A5;
    margin: 10rem auto;
    z-index: 1;
    
}

 .about {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100vh;
            background-color: crimson;
            z-index: 3;
            width: 100%;
            margin-top: -270px;
        }
.content{
 background-color: #0b2947;
}


/* Media Queries for tablet and mobile */

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    
    .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
    }

    nav {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        text-align: center;
    }

     nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
 
    nav ul li {
        margin-top: 5rem;
    }

     nav ul li a {
        margin 0;
        font-size: 3rem;
    }  

    nav ul li:first-child{
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .overlay.menu-open,
        nav.menu-open{
   display: flex;
   transform: scale(1);
   opacity: 1;
    }

  nav img {
      height: 15rem;
      margin: 0;
  }

  .menu {
      margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway|Coiny|Roboto|Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Jury Gregorio - Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="body">
        <header>
            <div class="menu-toggle" id="hamburger">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <nav>
                <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="menu">
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Contact</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btninfo">Info</a>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="content">
                <h1 class="possible">Everything is Possible</h1>
                <div class="circle">

                </div>
        </div>

        <div class="about">
            <h1>Helow</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var open = document.getElementById('hamburger');
        var changeIcon = true;

        open.addEventListener("click", function(){

        var overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
        var nav = document.querySelector('nav');
        var icon = document.querySelector('.menu-toggle i');

        overlay.classList.toggle("menu-open");
        nav.classList.toggle("menu-open");

        if (changeIcon) {
        icon.classList.remove("fa-bars");
        icon.classList.add("fa-times");

        changeIcon = false;
        }
        else {
        icon.classList.remove("fa-times");
        icon.classList.add("fa-bars");
        changeIcon = true;
        }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```